# Exit and entry stamps on European passports when leaving Schengen Area

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, passport-stamps, georgia-country, azerbaijan

Does a European passport get an exit stamp at the time of leaving Europe for Azerbaijan or Georgia? Also will the destination countries of Georgia and Azerbaijan put an entry stamp once you enter there?

Comment: By "Europe" do you mean "European Union"?  Or something else?  The answer will be different depending on which European country has issued the passport and which European country is being exited.

Comment: Let's say it's a Nordic country which is not part of EU but still part the European continent. Also will the destination countries of Georgia and Azerbaijan put an entry stamp once you enter there?

Comment: @Hosain, yes they do. For Azerbaijan, it looks like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Azerbaijan#/media/File:Azeri_stamps.png), for Georgia like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Georgia#/media/File:GeorgiaStamps.jpg).

Comment: @HosainSadeqi the only non-EU Nordic countries are Norway and Iceland, which are both in the Schengen area, so they both follow the Schengen area rule of not stamping passports issued by EU or Schengen area countries.

Comment: @phoog, although Iceland isn't in the continental Europe, as OP mentioned, your point is still valid.

Comment: @gdrt the OP did not specify continental Europe.  There is little doubt in my mind that an Icelandic passport is a "European passport," as are Irish and UK passports.

Comment: @gdrt I'm honoured - the Azeri stamps are mine :D

Comment: @phoog, they did in the comments: > *Let's say *it's a Nordic country which is not part of EU but still part [of] the **European continent***

Comment: @Coke, wow, what a coincidence. I hope you enjoyed your time in Azerbaijan, although it seems that you didn't spend much time there: you entered it from Georgia and then left the country by sea the other day.

Comment: Yeah that was the point!

Comment: @gdrt THe other way round: entered by ship from Kazakhstan and exited by bus to Georgia (where I used my Swedish ID; hence no Georgian stamps)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean leaving Schengen Area for Azerbaijan or Georgia, then, shortly:

- If you're a citizen of [EU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Union) or [EFTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Free_Trade_Association), then your passport won't get stamped.
- If you're **not** a citizen of EU or EDTA, then your passport will be stamped, because Azerbaijan and Georgia aren't in the [Schengen Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area).

For a longer answer, check Schengen Area section of [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passport_stamp#Schengen_Area) about passport stamps.

---

Regarding the second part of the question: yes, Azerbaijan and Georgia put an entry stamp once you enter these countries. For Azerbaijan, it looks like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Azerbaijan#/media/File:Azeri_stamps.png), for Georgia like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Georgia#/media/File:GeorgiaStamps.jpg).

Answer (score 2):

Passports of EU/Schengen states, Andorra, Monaco and San Marino are **never** stamped on leaving an EU/Schengen country, unless possibly if you ask for it.

Azerbaijan and Georgia do stamp all foreign passports (with Georgia also stamping their own passports on exit). If, for some reason, an EU citizen wants to avoid Georgian stamps, they can use a national ID card.

Comment: So is that possible to hold an ID card to enter Georgia instead of passport? Although Georgia isn't an EU/EFTA or even a continental member of Europe!? Does this rule apply to Azerbaijan as well?

Comment: @Hosain, you can enter Georgia with EU ID cards. For Azerbaijan, let alone you can't enter with ID cards, you have to apply for Electronic Visa, which you then need to print and present together with your passport.

Answer (score 2):

If you ask for a stamp, you *may* get one. Lithuanian border guards are really friendly and they stamped my Lithuanian passport in Kaunas (flying to UK) and in Vilnius (to Ukraine) and returning. However, Latvian officer on Russian border at Grebņova declined. British border guard at Luton also refused, so it depends on officer's mood.

Schengen border code says that Schengen/EU passports are not stamped, but the actual stamp cannot make illegal consequences for an EU/EFTA citizen, as they have a right to be in EU/EFTA for as long as they want.